# How to write type definitions while using nested navigation in react-navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I've write type definitions like [this document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/typescript.html) says, however here comes problem while I'm using nested navigation.

Here come the sample codes:

in my `App.tsx`

```
export type MainStackParamList = {
  Setting: undefined
}
export type TabParamList = {
  Home: undefined
  Personal: undefined
}
const MainStack = createNativeStackNavigator<MainStackParamList>()
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<TabParamList>()
const RootStack = createNativeStackNavigator()

const MainStackScreen = () => (
  <MainStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    <MainStack.Screen name="Setting" component={Setting} />
  </MainStack.Navigator>
)

const TabScreen = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Setting} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Personal" component={Setting} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
)

const RootStackScreen = () => (
  <RootStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    <RootStack.Screen name="Tab" component={TabScreen} />
    <RootStack.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen} />
  </RootStack.Navigator>
)
```

in `Home.tsx`

```
type HomeRouteProp = RouteProp<TabParamList, 'Home'>
type HomeNavigationProp = CompositeNavigationProp<
  BottomTabNavigationProp<TabParamList, 'Home'>,
  NativeStackNavigationProp<MainStackParamList>
>
type Props = {
  route: HomeRouteProp
  navigation: HomeNavigationProp
}

 // ...

 navigation.navigate('Main', { screen: 'Setting' })
```

and typescript says that cannot assign 'Main' to type 'Home' | 'Personal' | 'Setting'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need to add types for your root stack.

```
type RootStackParamList = {
  Tab: undefined;
  Main: undefined;
}
```

Then for your navigation prop:

```
// Navigation prop for your MainStack
type MainNavigationProp = CompositeNavigationProp<
  NativeStackNavigationProp<MainStackParamList, 'Setting'>,
  NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>
>

// Navigation prop for your Home
type HomeNavigationProp = CompositeNavigationProp<
  BottomTabNavigationProp<TabParamList, 'Home'>,
  MainNavigationProp
>
```

Combining navigation props using `CompositeNavigationProp` depends on nesting. Here, your `Home` screen is nested inside `MainStack`, so its navigation prop needs to be combined with `MainStack`'s navigation prop.

---

Previous answer:

In your Stack, you have `Setting` and in your tabs, you have `Home` and `Personal`. There's no definition for `Main` anywhere, so the error is correct.

Looks like your `Main` is your `MainStack`, which I guess you're rendering inside tabs? Then you need to add `Main: undefined` in `TabParamList`

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering me. I've updated my Navigator defines in the question detail. And in my case , `MainStack` are pages above tabs, not inside.

Comment: When I `navigation.navigate('Main', { screen: 'Setting' })`, tsc says that cannot assign `{ screen: string }` to `undefined`. I think this is because I've defined `Main: undefined` in `RootStackParamList `.

Comment: You can do `Main: { screen: keyof MainStackParamList }`

Comment: Thanks a lot, and I felt inspired to write some type like this `type NestedNavigator<T> = { screen: keyof T; params?: T[keyof T] }` and `Main: NextedNavigator<MainStackParamList>`

Comment: Thanks, improved @SunskyXH answer to make it even more type safe: `type NestedNavigatorParams<ParamList> = {
  [K in keyof ParamList]: undefined extends ParamList[K]
    ? { screen: K; params?: ParamList[K] }
    : { screen: K; params: ParamList[K] }
}[keyof ParamList]`

Answer (score 2):

To improve upon the comments in the accepted answer, `RootStackParamList` should be typed as

```
type RootStackParamList = {
  Tab: NavigatorScreenParams<TabParamList>;
  Main: NavigatorScreenParams<MainStackParamList>;
}
```