# How can I navigate from a top tab screen to a stack screen using react native navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack, expo-go, react-navigation-top-tabs

I'm making an expo application using react native. I have a stack navigator and I have a material top tab navigator as a stack screen. From ProfileAccountScreen I can navigate to the TopTabNavigator but I can NOT navigate from TopTabNavigator to another Stack screen?

```
`<NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="ProfileAccountScreen"
              component={ProfileAccountScreen}
              options={{ title: "Välkommen" }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="TopTabNavigator" 
              component={TopTabNavigator}
              options={{ headerShown: false }} 
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="CreateTaskScreen"
              component={CreateTaskScreen}
              options={{ title: "Skapa syssla" }}
            />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>`
```

Here is the TopTabNavigator:

```
`const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export default function TopTabNavigator() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="SomeScreen" component={SomeScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}`
```

The problem is that I can't find any good documents that explain how to navigate between a top tab navigation screen to a stack screen. And in my RootStackParamList I have TopTabNavigator and not the screens since it's the whole top-navigator as a stack screen.

I have tried using navigation as Props type like this:

```
`type Props = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, "TopTaskNavigator"> & {
  profileNavigation: NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList>;
};`

`export default function HouseholdTasksScreen({ navigation }: Props) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Här visas alla tasks för det valda hushållet</Text>
      <Button
        title="Navigera till att skapa syssla"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("CreateTaskScreen")}
      ></Button>
    </View>
  );
}`
```

and in this case I get an error message:

```
`Type '({ navigation }: Props) => Element' is not assignable to type 'ScreenComponentType<ParamListBase, "TopTaskNavigator"> | undefined'.`
```

**The things is that the tab navigator needs to both say where it is (in the tabparamlist) AND say where to navigate (in the stackparamlist) i think??**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write type definitions while using nested navigation in react-navigation v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59816529/how-to-write-type-definitions-while-using-nested-navigation-in-react-navigation)

Answer (score -2):

See [useScrollToTop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-scroll-to-top/) on ReactNavigation.org docs

you can use this hook.

```
const ref = React.useRef(null);

useScrollToTop(ref);

return <ScrollView ref={ref}>{/* content */}</ScrollView>;
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question